# What does . or / stand for in java servlet/spring/struts?

Tags: java

In a project while giving a path for a package or a file name we often use `.` or `/`  what is the importance of each. For example

```
src/main/resources
|
|-ftl
   |
   |-css, hello.ftl
      |
      |-images, helloCss.css
          |
          |-pic.jpeg
```

i am trying to include a css file in the hello.ftl freemarker template but it doent seem to take it `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/helloCss.css"/>`

Comment: `.` mean current directory, `/` path separator, and also filesystem root.

Answer (score 1):

when using `ClassPath.getRessource()` you need to use `'/'` instead of `'.'` to denote a resource in a `java package`, since `java packages` are delimited using `'.'` but other files may contain the `'.'` character in their name (in contrast to `java packages` and `classes`).

EDIT: Your problem is where `src/main/ressources` get's deployed to. Since I do not know your project configuration I cannot tell you at which path `helloCss.css` will be located at in the final web project.

EDIT2: Since `'.'` at the beginning of a path denotes the current directory (credits to user1516873, see comment), that is the most probable cause of your problem.

Comment: what if it is a java standalone maven project?